# Add documentation to entity framework generated entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, code-generation

T4 enerate for me some entities like this :

```
public partial class Use
{

    public int UseId { get; set; }
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime InUseDate { get; set; }
}
```

i whant to add documentation to this entity. i proceed like folowing:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UseData))]
public partial class Use { 

}
public class UseData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is an ID
    /// </summary>
    [Display(
        Name = "Use ID",
        Description = "This is an ID Desc")
    ]
    public int UseId;
}
```

but VS autocomplete dont show me the summary of my UseIdattribute.

any ideas

Comment: Nice try but I would not have expected this to work. A Metadata class is used to look up attributes (metadata) on properties, the XML comments are not metadata.

Comment: Use the EF Reverse POCO template! http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Comment: yes, that's what i thought Henk. I tried to add the summary comment directly to my second partial class but it dosent works, VS tell me that my attribute is already defined.

Comment: I think the _property_ is already defined.

Comment: @ErikEJ - how would that help, exactly? You can doctor any T4 to add "Gets or sets the UseId".

Comment: @Henk That template can get the description from SQL Server meta data

Comment: Right, that might be a solution. But formally the wrong place to describe the C# properties.

Comment: i fond a solution here :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931159/add-documentation-to-generated-code-in-entity-framework-model-first). auto generated from my edmx model

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an EDMX all you have to do is go to the entity property in the designer, open the Visual Studio properties tab and fill in the documentation[image: Screenshot of VS EDMX Properties].

Generates code with xml summary...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Database and Application Version
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 MajorVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return _MajorVersion;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_MajorVersion != value)
            {
                OnMajorVersionChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("MajorVersion");
                _MajorVersion = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("MajorVersion");
                OnMajorVersionChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```