# edmproperty.documentation is null

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to modify template SSDLToSQL10.tt to add Ducumentation property to generated sql

```
--<#=prop.Documentation!= null? prop.Documentation.Summary: "null" #>
```

as described at http://joyofexcellence.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/16/xml-comments-for-entity-framework/ and this question [Add documentation to generated code in entity framework model first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931159/add-documentation-to-generated-code-in-entity-framework-model-first)
but prop.Documentation is always null. Is there any way to resolve problem?
I m using VS2013 and EntityFramework.6.1.1/ModelFirst

Comment: Read [Add documentation to generated code in entity framework model first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931159/add-documentation-to-generated-code-in-entity-framework-model-first)

Comment: it works for generating classes, but not fro generating sql. Dont know why