# Get column description from mdf file in CSharpDbContext.Types.tt

Tags: c#, t4, mdf

I'm modifying CSharpDbContext.Types.tt file.

I want to use column description as comment of fields in entity class.

I'd to ask how to get description of columns from mdf file and then set to EdmProperty.Documentation in CSharpDbContext.Types.tt file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOZuF.png

Comment: Rather than editing the question, you should self answer in the answer section and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will move my solution to answer area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a long day, I have found a solution

1. Generate entity documentation from table/column description.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mthamil.EntityDesignerDocumentationGenerator

2. Generate comment from entity documentation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149605/2608958